# What happens to a Google Docs history and comments when a user is deleted

Tags: google-drive, google-docs, google-drive-sharing

If a user is deleted from an organization (no ownership transfer, etc. just deleted), and that user had collaborated on some Google Docs shared with them (not owned by them), what happens to the history of the edits for that Doc and what happens to comments they made in the Doc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Content they added to other documents will still be there, there's no change. Comments will still be there, but will show the deleted user's name and a the default grey colored profile photo.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I see the history but only "Deleted User"  I really wish I could see the name!

[image]